# Stuck in writing python list reduction program

Tags: python, list, reduction

I am stuck in writing the python code for below problem, can anyone help to find the issue with the code is much appreciated.

List Reduction:

You are given a list of integers L having size N and an integer K. You can perform the following operation on the list at most k times:

- Pick any two elements of the list.
- Multiply any element by 2.
- Divide the other element by 2, taking the ceiling if element is odd.

Note: that after such an operation, the list is changed and the changed list will be used in subsequent operations.

You need to minimize the sum of all elements present in the list after performing at most k such operations.

Input Format:

- First line contains N K as described above.
- The second line contains N space separated integers, representing the list initially,

Output Format:

Print the minimum possible sum of all elements in the list at the end, after performing at most k operations.

Code:

```
def solve (X, arr):
    Sum = 0
    largestDivisible, minimum = -1, arr[0]
    for i in range(0,N):
        Sum += arr[i]
        if(arr[i]%X == 0 and largestDivisible < arr[i]):
            largestDivisible = arr[i]
        if arr[i] < minimum:
            minimum = arr[i]
    if largestDivisible == -1:
        return Sum

    sumAfterOperation = (Sum-minimum-largestDivisible+(X*minimum)+(largestDivisible//X))
    return min(Sum,sumAfterOperation)
    

N=5 
X =2
#map(int, input().split())
arr = [10, 7, 4, 2, 1]
#list(map(int, input().split()))

out_ = solve(X, arr)
print (out_)
output: 20
```

expected output: 19

Comment: Why 19 is the expected answer?

Comment: Explanation:
We can achieve min sum 19 in two operations as follows: 
Operation 1: Pick 10 and 2. Multiply 2 by 2, divide 10 by 2. New list becomes: (5,7,4,4,1) 
Operation 2: Pick 7 and 1. Multiply 1 by 2, divide 7 by 2. New list becomes: (5,4,4,4,2], whose sum of elements is 19.
 It can be verified that we cannot achieve a sum less than 19 in at most 2 steps.

Comment: I don't quite see how you can ask to find the issue when you surely know full well that you're only doing one operation instead of K.

Comment: Your solution dont check odd numbers. You need add 1 to result of ```//``` for odd values

Comment: Thank you, finally i got the expected output 

Comment: Welcome. My solution with python function in answers.

Comment: Added algorithm like your variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not optimal program.

Idea: Multiplying the minimal element and dividing the maximal element gives sequence with minimal total sum. Do you want process negative numbers? Does K take negative values?

```
K = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

for _ in range(K):
    arr.sort()
    arr[0] *= 2
    arr[-1] = arr[-1] // 2 + arr[-1] % 2

print(sum(arr))
```

More effective solution.

```
K = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

for _ in range(K):
    mn, mx = min(arr), max(arr)
    mn_i = arr.index(mn)
    if mn != mx:
        mx_i = arr.index(mx)
    else:
        mx_i = arr.index(mx, mn_i+1)
    arr[mn_i] *= 2
    arr[mx_i] = arr[mx_i] // 2 + arr[mx_i] % 2
print(sum(arr))
```

And algorithmic solution.

```
K = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

for _ in range(K):
    mn, mx = 0, 0
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        if x < arr[mn]:
            mn = i
        if x >= arr[mx]:
            mx = i
    arr[mn] *= 2
    arr[mx] = arr[mx] // 2 + arr[mx] % 2

print(sum(arr))
```

Comment: K will not take negative numbers.

Comment: @Padhu why are you check remainder to K into max finding algo?

Comment: @KellyBundy I excepted 17. It result less.

Comment: What result do you get when you change K to let's say 100?

Comment: @KellyBundy 20. For large values algorithm will be return smoothed sequences. [4, 4, 4, 4, 3] and [6, 4, 4, 4, 2] for example from task description.

Comment: @Eugene Ah, right. I was thinking it would explode. Oh well... 20 is still wrong.